# How this dictionary works in simpleubjson encode in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wounder how this works, I wrote a simple binary exporter similar format json to simpleubjson not same, but my codes is slower while simipleubjson is faster and I noticed simplubjson use a dictionary that accept type as key, can you please guide me how it works?

dispatch = {}

```
def __init__(self, default=None):
    self._default = default or self.default

def default(self, obj):
    raise EncodeError('unable to encode %r' % obj)

def encode_next(self, obj):
    tobj = type(obj)
    if tobj in self.dispatch:
        res = self.dispatch[tobj](self, obj)
    else:
        return self.encode_next(self._default(obj))
    if isinstance(res, bytes):
        return res
    return bytes().join(res)

def encode_noop(self, obj):
    return NOOP
dispatch[type(NOOP_SENTINEL)] = encode_noop

def encode_none(self, obj):
    return NULL
dispatch[type(None)] = encode_none

def encode_bool(self, obj):
    return TRUE if obj else FALSE
dispatch[bool] = encode_bool

def encode_int(self, obj):
    if (-2 ** 7) <= obj <= (2 ** 7 - 1):
        return INT8 + CHARS[obj % 256]
    elif (-2 ** 15) <= obj <= (2 ** 15 - 1):
        return INT16 + pack('>h', obj)
    elif (-2 ** 31) <= obj <= (2 ** 31 - 1):
        return INT32 + pack('>i', obj)
    elif (-2 ** 63) <= obj <= (2 ** 63 - 1):
        return INT64 + pack('>q', obj)
    else:
        return self.encode_decimal(Decimal(obj))
dispatch[int] = encode_int
dispatch[long] = encode_int
```

Answer (score 0):

This works because it is a dictionary of functions for each type that it encodes. This provides O(1) lookup for which function to use to encode a type, vs an O(n) lookup for if/elseif statements to check against each type.

Some links with more information:

[Why store a function inside a python dictionary?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182093/why-store-a-function-inside-a-python-dictionary)

[Dictionary of Methods/Functions (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65126-dictionary-of-methodsfunctions/)